# How to make a "user active" layout like Facebook/Messenger

Tags: android, xml

So, here is my XML file for my user layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/users_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_image"
            app:civ_border_color="#696969"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/username_layout"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="username"
                android:textColor="#353758"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_item_online"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/user_state"
                android:visibility="visible"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how it looks :
 [image: user_layout]

but I want it just like facebook or messenger, I mean when a user is online the dot is attached to his profile picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest unsing `ConstraintLayout` for this. It's easier! For `ConstraintLayout` you need to add this dependency into your `build.gradle` app file:

`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`

Then you can do it like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/users_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_image"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#696969"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="username"
        android:textColor="#353758"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/users_profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_item_online"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user_state"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:translationX="-14dp"
        android:translationY="-14dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/users_profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/users_profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/users_profile_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/users_profile_image"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a parent layout (LinearLayout)
2. Create a child layout for profile image (RelativeLayout)
3. Add the online icon to profile image’s layout and add ‘ android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"’ and ‘ android:layout_alignParentRight="true"’
4. Add the textview (for name) to your parent layout.